# What causes a spike in volume at EOD for ETFs?

Tags: stocks, investing, etf

Most ETFs seem to experience a massive surge in volume in the last 2-3 minutes before the bell 3-5 days a week. Is this activity a symptom of the market makers trades or just a graphical bug? It seems to be present on 80% of the ETFS I look at. I imagine it's something obvious, but I can't find any information on it.

Comment: 80% of ETFs sounds extreme.  Can you give some examples - preferably of large, liquid ETFs.  In the case of leveraged ETFs it may simply be day traders squaring their positions at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2):

Many market participants use Market-On-Close orders to execute trades as close to the end of the trading session as possible.

Other market participants want to close positions since they have no control of the capital after hours.